# IOS app only takes up full screen after second launch

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing an app using Cordova. When I launch the app for the first time on a device (both simulator and live), there is a black border and the content is shrunk. If I exit it and relaunch it a second time, the app takes up the full screen as expected.

Also, when I run it in the simulator on an iPad, it is offset down and to the right slightly. Some content ends up cut off. How do I correct this?

I have tried it with and without viewport-fit=cover and with and without the splashscreen plugin.

[image: App is offsetted on simulator]